# Plot normal distribution in python, matplotlib, multi-arm bandit

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

How can I plot multiple normal distribution-like images in matplotlib, like the one above?

Answer (score 5):

This kind of plot is called a "violin" plot:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate 5 actions with different reward distributions
data = np.random.randn(1000, 5) * [1, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5] + [0, 1, -1, 2, -0.5]

plt.violinplot(data)
plt.xlabel('Action')
plt.ylabel('Reward distribution')
```

[image]